# NSManagedObjectContext doesnt fetch or save object when application is pushed to background

Tags: iphone, core-data, background, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsoperationqueue

In my app I have a parent child context decared. While saving objects to core data that process itself is done in a **dispatch_async** . In foreground everything works fine but when the app is pushed to background the fetch request and save operations are held up. Also I am using **NSOperationQueue** to queue up my operations. While in foreground where all operations work fine Memory usage is stable but when pushed to background even memory consumptions increases by huge amounts and app crashes under memory pressure.

```
- (void) saveDocument:(ALEXDocument*)document forDownloaded:(BOOL)isDownloadCompleted
{

    BOOL checkWithKillDocId = NO;
    if(!document.tocId || [document.tocId isEqualToString:@""])
        document.tocId = nil;

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self getNewPrivateManagedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request         = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity     = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate;

    if (![document.killDocId isEqual:[NSNull null]] && document.killDocId!= nil)
    {
        if(![document.killDocId isEqualToString:@"(null)"] && ![document.killDocId isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"killDocId = %@",document.killDocId];
            checkWithKillDocId = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            predicate                       = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"reference == %@ AND section = %d AND tocRelation.tocId = %@ ", document.reference,document.section,document.tocId];
            checkWithKillDocId = NO;
        }

    }
    else
    {
         predicate                       = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"reference == %@ AND section = %d AND tocRelation.tocId = %@ ", document.reference,document.section,document.tocId];
        checkWithKillDocId = NO;
    }

    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;

    Document *coreDataDoc          = (Document*)[[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Document");
    if (!coreDataDoc || coreDataDoc == nil)
    {
        if(checkWithKillDocId)
        {
            predicate                       = [ NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"reference == %@ AND section = %d AND tocRelation.tocId = %@ ", document.reference,document.section,document.tocId];
            [request setPredicate:predicate];
            coreDataDoc          = (Document*)[[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] lastObject];
            if (!coreDataDoc || coreDataDoc == nil)
            {
                coreDataDoc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            }
        }
        else
        {
             coreDataDoc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        }

    }

    coreDataDoc.anchorName          = document.anchorName;
    coreDataDoc.binary              = document.binary;
    coreDataDoc.contentSize         = [NSNumber numberWithInt:document.contentSize];
    coreDataDoc.copyright           = document.copyright;
    coreDataDoc.createdDate         = document.date;
    coreDataDoc.domain              = document.domain;
    coreDataDoc.fileName            = document.fileName;
    coreDataDoc.htmlContent         = document.htmlContent;
    coreDataDoc.mimeType            = document.mimeType;
    coreDataDoc.reference           = document.reference;
    coreDataDoc.section             = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:document.section];
    coreDataDoc.source              = document.source;
    coreDataDoc.title               = document.title;

    coreDataDoc.tocReference        = document.tocReference;
    coreDataDoc.nextReference       = document.nextReference;
    coreDataDoc.nextSection         = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",document.nextSection];
    coreDataDoc.previousReference   = document.previousReference;
    coreDataDoc.previousSection     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",document.previousSection];
    coreDataDoc.downloadedDate      = [NSDate date];
    coreDataDoc.status              = document.documentStatus;
    coreDataDoc.killDocId           = document.killDocId;
    [self dbSaveInContext:context];
//    context = nil;
//    coreDataDoc = nil;
//    [context reset];
//    [context refreshObject:coreDataDoc mergeChanges:NO];
    NSLog(@"Context");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To run any process in background you need to tell iOS that your app will continue and complete task.

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Not running background tasks anymore.");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
    backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

It will let you run any task in background for short time period. (10minutes to 5Sec).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but the issue I am facing is the NSManasgedObjectContext defined above halts all execution when in background whereas it works in foreground properly

Comment: are you checking the backgroundtasktime. it might be less then the time require to complete the task.

Comment: [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining.